# Adding a row with variable in sql

Tags: variables, insert, sql-server-2012, row, insert-into

I'm trying to add a calculated row to a table using the Insert Into. 
So roughly i'm trying to add and split the following:

```
     [RFC]       [Tons]
[1]   NAME 1       30
[2]   NAME 2       50
[3]   NAME 2       30
[4]   NAME 2       20
```

So that I get:

```
     [RFC]       [Tons]
[1]   NAME 1       30
[2]   NAME 2       42
[3]   NAME 2       58
```

As you can see, I added all of Name 2 and then divided into two rows: one that has 42% of the total, and one for 58% of the total.

Adding the calculated variable is pretty straightforward:

First I declare my variable which is

```
DECLARE @TonsE int;
SET @TonsE = CASE 
WHEN 
(SELECT SUM(mkt_impotemporal.Tons)*0.42 FROM mkt_impotemporal where RFC='EHP040219KX0' GROUP BY RFC) is null THEN 0 
ELSE 
(SELECT SUM(mkt_impotemporal.Tons)*0.42 FROM mkt_impotemporal where RFC='EHP040219KX0' GROUP BY RFC) 
END;
```

Then I add:

```
INSERT INTO mkt_impotemporal 
VALUES 
('EHP040219KX0',
@TonsE)
```

However, now i'm stuck with a new row with 42% of the total, but can't seem to change the remaining rows to reflect only 58% of their original values, even if I run an update BEFORE I insert the new row (I'm not sure how it works but it seems as though the variable does not "store" the number for another query).

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko SQL 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing would be to use a second variable and compute its value before doing your inserts.

```
DECLARE @TonsE int;
SET @TonsE = CASE 
WHEN 
(SELECT SUM(mkt_impotemporal.Tons)*0.42 FROM mkt_impotemporal where RFC='EHP040219KX0' GROUP BY RFC) is null THEN 0 
ELSE 
(SELECT SUM(mkt_impotemporal.Tons)*0.42 FROM mkt_impotemporal where RFC='EHP040219KX0' GROUP BY RFC) 
END;

DECLARE @TonsE2 int;
SET @TonsE = CASE 
WHEN 
(SELECT SUM(mkt_impotemporal.Tons)*0.58 FROM mkt_impotemporal where RFC='EHP040219KX0' GROUP BY RFC) is null THEN 0 
ELSE 
(SELECT SUM(mkt_impotemporal.Tons)*0.58 FROM mkt_impotemporal where RFC='EHP040219KX0' GROUP BY RFC) 
END;

--DELETE FROM mkt_impotemporal WHERE RFC = 'EHP040219KX0'

INSERT INTO mkt_impotemporal 
VALUES 
('EHP040219KX0',
@TonsE);

INSERT INTO mkt_impotemporal 
VALUES 
('EHP040219KX0',
@TonsE2)
```

Comment: I had actually created another table to store the numbers before, erase and copy again, but your solution is much more elegant/efficient. Thanks!!